# ksh: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I am trying to write a script to output lines which fulfill a certain criteria into a new .txt file, trying to combined unix and awk

been googling but keep getting this error:syntax error near unexpected token `done'

```
Filename="bishan"
file="659.A"
while IFS= read line
do
   cat $Filename.txt | awk '{ otherSubNo = substr($0,73,100);gsub(/    
   /,"",otherSubNo); if(length(otherSubNo)>8){ print "Subscriber Number is
   ",": ",substr($0,1,20)," Other Subscriber Number is ", " :    
   ",substr($0,73,100) }}'| wc -l >> $Filename.txt 
done <"$file"
```

example of 659.A is as follows:
This is the first line of the 659.a file:

6581264562          201611050021000000002239442239460000000019010000010081866368

```
        00C0525016104677451     100C 0                                  0000
```

0111000 000000000000000000006598540021          01010000000000659619778001010000
000000659854000300000000000000000000    004700001

Please help, I have been googling about this but no avail

Comment: I can't reproduce the symptom. Is that the entire script? Do you not have a `#!` line at the top?

Comment: yes I do have this top line
     #!/bin/ksh

Comment: Then you need to update your question to show the *entire* copy-and-pasted script that exhibits the problem. Also show the exact copy-and-pasted error message. Since you don't know what's causing the problem, by definition you don't know what information you can safely omit (like the `#!` line) -- so don't omit anything. If your script is too big, trim it down -- but make sure that the script you post actually exhibits the problem. [mcve]

Comment: i can't see an error but your code is so poorly formatted that its difficult to tell

Comment: @glennjackman: I copy-and-pasted the code and ran it on my system. The error did not occur. The error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the specified error, albeit only with close approximation, by typing the script in notepad (windows) and testing it in cygwin.

script.sh:

```
while read myline
do
echo $myline
done
```

In ksh:

```
~> /usr/bin/ksh ./script.sh
: not found
./script.sh[7]: syntax error: 'done' unexpected
```

In bash:

```
~> /usr/bin/bash ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./script.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./script.sh: line 6: `done'
```

The said error (at least, in my case) is because of the CRLF characters. When I copy-paste the code to cygwin, the CRLF turns to LF (along with all invisible control characters that get lost), thus making the error disappear.